# Angular partial not rendering

Tags: angularjs, partial

I'm trying to render a partial in Angular, but it is not rendering. Am I missing something?

```
Partial here: <div ng-include="partial.html"></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial.html">
  test
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` expects an expression that results in a template url. If you need to pass a string, use quotes (in addition to the double-quotes of the attribute):

```
<div ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
```